# LoadString Will Not Return a Read-Only Pointer

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm running into strange behavior with LoadString on a recent project. For some reason, if I attempt to load a string with `cchBufferMax` set to zero to obtain a read-only pointer, LoadString returns a `-1`, which doesn't seem to fall within documented behavior. If I pass in a buffer with a non-zero size, the string is loaded correctly.

The following will return `-1` and `lpAppName` remains unmodified:

```cpp
LPCSTR lpAppName;
LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APPNAME, reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&lpAppName), 0);
```

However, the following works as expected:

```cpp
char cAppName[64];
LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APPNAME, cAppName, sizeof(cAppName));
```

In both cases, `IDS_APPNAME` is the same (`#define`'d as `200` in `resource.h`).

Any ideas?

Comment: "*LoadString returns a -1, which doesn't seem to fall within documented behavior*" - it does if you read between the lines. It is documented as returning a non-zero size if the resource exists, and returning 0 if the resource does not exist. Thus, what can it return if it fails? It must return a negative value on failure, and you can use `GetLastError()` to find out why.  So, what does `GetLastError()` actually return in your case?

Comment: That was my thought as well, however `GetLastError()` returns `0` in this case.

Comment: Make sure you're not making any other API calls between the call to LoadString and the call to GetLastError.

Comment: I wonder how `LoadStringA` behaves when `hInstance` contains a UTF-16 encoded string table resource.

Comment: @IInspectable all string table resources are UTF-16. But you bring up a good point. If the goal is to get a pointer directly to a resource, it's probably better to use LoadStringW() instead to work with the resource's native format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All string resources are natively Unicode in the final executable. But you are clearly not compiling your app for Unicode (as evident by your use of `LP(C)STR` with `LoadString()`, otherwise the code would not compile). So, `LoadString()` is mapped to `LoadStringA()`, which can copy a Unicode string into an ANSI buffer (as in your 2nd example), but cannot return a direct ANSI pointer to Unicode data. This is a mistake in MSDN's documentation for `LoadStringA()`.

To do what you are attempting, you need to use `LoadStringW()` instead:

```
LPCWSTR lpAppName = nullptr;
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APPNAME, reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&lpAppName), 0);
```

I found the following comment on CodeProject that confirms this:

https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/5938019/Re-LoadString-with-cchBufferMax-equalsequals-0

> The current Microsoft version of the Win32 documentation says that LoadString, LoadStringW, and LoadStringA will pass back a pointer to a read-only copy of a string resource, if the buffer size passed to the routine is 0. In which universe does this happen? ...
>
> ...
>
> Solved: receiving a pointer to the string when cchBufferMax == 0 happens in the Unicode universe (LoadStringW), not the MBCS universe (LoadStringA). Duh! Of course. String resource data is Unicode. If I'd looked at Wine's LoadStringW instead of LoadStringA I'd have seen that yesterday.
>
> (And in case anyone stumbles on this discussion for info about this feature, note that the string in the resource is likely not null terminated.).
>
> I'll post feedback for the documentation. It was an error that the same copy got pasted into both LoadString descriptions. LoadStringA needs to have the part about cchBufferMax == 0 deleted. The -1 return value should also be documented. (Also, LoadStringW does not throw exceptions with a NULL buffer pointer, it returns 0, but that doesn't need to be documented.)

Comment: Thanks! My string resource was defined using an ANSI string, so I assumed this would carry over into calls to `LoadStringA` via `LoadString`. I apologize that I can't mark this as the answer since I don't have enough standing on SO as of yet.